# Karatzas + Shreve 2.22: For optional time $S$, stopping time $T$, prove that $\mathscr{F}_{S+} \subset \mathscr{F}_T$

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times, filtrations

> Prove that if $S$ is an optional time and $T$ is a positive stopping time such that  with $S \le T$ and $S < T$ on $\{S < \infty\}$, then $\mathscr{F}_{S+} \subset \mathscr{F}_T$.

The following is the given solution:

Consider any $A \in \mathscr{F}_{S+}$, which means that $\forall t \ge 0, A \cap \{S \le t\} \in \mathscr{F}_{t+}$. Then:

\begin{align*}
  A &= \left( \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{Q}} [A \cap \{S < r < T \}] \right) \cup [A \cap \{S = \infty\}] \\
\end{align*}

For the left clause, $A \cap \{S < r < T\} = A \cap \{S < r \} \cap \{T > r\}$ is in $\mathscr{F}_T$ because $A \cap \{S < r\} \in \mathscr{F}_r$.

For the right clause, $A \cap \{S = \infty\} = [A \cap \{S = \infty\} ] \cap \{T = \infty\}$ is in $\mathscr{F}_T$. Then the conclusion follows.

All of that makes sense except I don't see how we can conclude that $A \cap \{S < r\} \in \mathscr{F}_r$

Comment: I get that part. I don't get the earlier part how we say that $A \cap \{S < r\} \in \mathscr{F}_t$

Comment: I think there is a typo. In fact no $t$ has been specified. So it should read $A\cap \{S<r\} \in \mathcal F_r$.

Comment: yikes, you are right, that should have been $\mathscr{F}_r$. I fixed it. However, I still don't understand how you get that. Of course $\{ S < r \} \in \mathscr{F}_r$, that is the optional time property. But why is $A \cap \{S < r\} \in \mathscr{F}_r$?

Comment: Since $A \in \mathscr{F}_{S+}$, that means for any $t \ge 0$, we have $A \cap \{S \le t\} \in \mathscr{F}_{t+}$. We can change notation to get for any $r \ge 0$, we have $A \cap \{S \le r\} \in \mathscr{F}_{r+}$. How can you infer from that that $A \cap \{S < r\} \in \mathscr{F}_r$? Can't we have $A \in \mathscr{F}_{r+}$ but $A \not\in\ \mathscr{F}_r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from the definition of $\mathcal{F_{S+}}$.
Recall that $A \cap \{S \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F_{t+}},\forall t\geq 0$.
Now, $A \cap \{S < r\} = A \cap ( \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{S\leq r-\frac{1}{n}\}) = \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A \cap \{ S \leq r- \frac{1}{n} \})$. But $A \cap \{ S \leq r- \frac{1}{n} \} \in \mathcal{F_{(r-\frac{1}{n})+}} \subset \mathcal{F_{r}} \forall n$. Therefore, the union is in $\mathcal{F_{r}}$.

Comment: Thank you! That's rather simple in hindsight after you've explained it :)